# How to know which methods to implement when extending a class

Tags: android, inheritance, interface, reference

I know this might be a basic question, but I do need an answer. I am using Android Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html and want to know how I can possibly know which methods I need to implement when extending the class by reading the reference. I am trying to create a class that extends BaseAdapter, and I cannot find the information on the reference link above as to which interface methods I need to implement. Android Studio does tell me which methods that I am missing, but I want to know how to know them in the first place by reading the official reference.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

public ItemAdapter(Context context){
    ...
}

public Object getItem(int position) { return items.get(position);}
public long getItemId(int position) { return position;}

public int getCount(){
    ...
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
}
```

As I am reading through the link above, I cannot see that I need to implement getItem(), getItmId(), getCount(), and getView() in order to extend BaseAdapter; the above code has no error. I can find inherited methods from the interface Basic Adapter implemented under the Inherited Methods section, but the section has more abstract methods than I need to get my class working.

Comment: In android studio you should be able to press `CTRL`+ `i` or `CMD` + `i` if you`re on Mac Os X and the IDE should give you a list of methods to implement. If not search for *implement* in *Preferences->KeyMap*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only abstract methods must be implemented when extending a class. Check if there're any abstract methods in `BaseAdapter` class. Then check if the super class or interfaces which `BaseAdapter` extends\implements have abstract methods left not implemented.

Comment: How can I know which abstract methods the interface of BaseAdapter has, are left unimplemented? I see that Adapter interface has 10 abstract methods on the reference link above but cannot be sure as to which one is unimplemented.

Comment: Just check whether the abstract methods of interfaces are overriden by its subclass(`BaseAdapter` in this case) or not. If not, you must implement it in your own concrete class.